# How to specify an class NOT to select with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a web-scraping project that extracts links out of an article and I want to be able to specify the search to just the main body of text, but am running into trouble with false-positives on the navigational links at the bottom.

I know that all of these false positives fall under the same specific class in the html, but I don't know how to specify *not* to search there.

This is the code I currently have and I want to specify not to search descendants of class="footer-wikiwalk-nav"

```
        url = searchlinks.get()
        c = requests.get(url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(c.content, 'lxml')

        parent_url = 'https://EXAMPLEURL.com'
        surfacelinks = [parent_url + str(l) for l, t in list(set([(a.get('href'), 
                    a.get_text()) for a in bs.select('[href*="str"]')])) 
                    if 'STR' in t]
```

Comment: Use `:not(.footer-wikiwalk-nav)` in the selector.

Comment: Most of the SCP Wiki pages with their [source-text can be found on GitHub: extracted with _wikidot-css-extractor_](https://emmiegit.github.io/wikidot-css-extractor/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
bs.select('[href*="str"]:not(.footer-wikiwalk-nav)')
```

like Barmar suggested [see the [pseudo-classes section](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:not) of the soupsieve docs for more details].

You could also use

```py
bs.find_all(href=lambda h: h and "str" in h, class_= lambda c: 'footer-wikiwalk-nav' not in c.split())
```

(but `select` is probably preferable...)

Comment: Beautiful Soup since version 4.7 supports [CSS-selectors via _SoupSieve_ library](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors).  The [_negation_ psuedo-class `:not(X)`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) exists since CSS 3 (Selectors Level 3, recommended 2018).

Comment: @hc_dev thanks? since op was already using `select` I assumed they know how `select` basically works...

Comment: It's not about this question only, but for all future visitors. They should know why SoupSieve is mentioned and which BS-version to use or that other standard CSS selectors are supported as well.